# How to integrate a differential equation of the following form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have an equation of the form,

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(f(r,\theta) g(r) \frac{\partial \phi(r,\theta)}{\partial r} - g(r)\frac{\partial \phi(r,\theta)}{\partial r} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( f(r,\theta) \frac{\partial \phi(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right) $$

which I want to solve for $\phi(r,\theta)$. However, I am completely stumped for where to even start. Do methods exist for solving an equation like this, and if so could someone refer me to then or (even better), provide a solution.

Thanks

Comment: I'll leave that problem to people having secret information about the functions $f(r,\theta)$ and $g(r)$, because it's quite crucial for analytical or numerical solutions.

Comment: Could you expand on that comment? How might potential methods differ based on the form of $f(r,\theta)$ and $g(r)$?

Comment: If I asked you to calculate $\int^1_0f(x)\,dx$, would it help if I told you what $f$ is supposed to mean?